# sas 9.3 user deleted and created again Users Folders

Tags: metadata, sas, 4gl

problem is like below:
we have user 'Mike' in SAS metadata
Mike has personal folder in metadata 'User Folders/Mike/My Folder'

Mike was deleted (accidentally).
We created user Mike again; now Mike has personal folder in metadata 'User Folders/Mike(1)/My Folder'

is there a method to tell SAS Metadata that mike's personal folder should be this one:
'User Folders/Mike/My Folder'
and not this one:
'User Folders/Mike(1)/My Folder'

i found METADATA_SETASSN function but have no idea how to use it

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Type `metabrowse` in the SAS IDE.  This will prompt you for a server and connection credentials.

Once connected to the server, go to "Persons"->"Mike"->"AssociatedHomeFolder"  Copy the object ID.

Then use the Data Step functions for updating the value.  See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrmeta/64857/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19f60h644gvcrn14jcrwqngislv.htm